# Microphone Permission of Flask app in python-for-android and buildozer

Tags: javascript, python, android, buildozer

I'm converting a flaskapp combined with SpeechRecognition Javascript into an apk (I get the html [here](https://bes.works/dev/test/webspeech/)) . And i tried to add the Microphone permission by adding:

Python:

```
from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions 
request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET,Permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,Permission.RECORD_AUDIO])
```

`Buildozer.spec`

```
android.permissions = INTERNET,RECORD_AUDIO,MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.api = 30
```

But when i run apk, i still got `not-allowed` error in javascript.

Thanks For Any Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be because webview used in android might not have permissions handler. Assuming you used setWebViewClient or setWebChromeClient based on documentation [doclink](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient)

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            myRequest = request;
            for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                if (permission.equals("android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE")) {
                    demandForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                } else {
                    myRequest.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest request) {
        super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request);
    }
```

Try [adding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECORD_AUDIO) and [handling](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onPermissionRequest(android.webkit.PermissionRequest)) permission to correct this issue.

Comment: I don't have much experiences in java, i just buid apk with p4a and buildozer. Butcan  you add more specific information about something like how can i add it or where can i use. Also i found that P4a Webview using webview jni (Maybe it will helps!). But thanks you for your attention

Comment: Sure, [link](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/?highlight=webview#webview) try adding permission to webview

Comment: Sorry , i am very busied in few days ago . So i couldn't reply, and this documention is for python-for-android. I have readed it , and try to adding some permissions. But they didn't work. But i find something [that](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/3107e4e788e152fc3c69e0ff67702d670a23d970/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/webview/build/src/main/java/org/kivy/android/PythonActivity.java) is the Java code of webview. Maybe i can try to add code into it . But thanks you